# Qt 5.3 OpenGL - vertex buffer object drawing using the core profile

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, compatibility

Im using Qt 5.3 to create a QWindow to do some basic rendering stuff. The QWindow is declared like this:

```
 class OpenGLWindow : public QWindow, protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core
 {
     Q_OBJECT
     ...
 }
```

It is initialized in the constructor:

```
OpenGLWindow::OpenGLWindow(QWindow *parent) : QWindow(parent)
{
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setVersion(3,3);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);

    this->setSurfaceType(OpenGLSurface);
    this->setFormat(format);
    this->create();

    _context = new QOpenGLContext;
    _context->setFormat(format);
    _context->create();

    _context->makeCurrent(this);
    this->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    ...
}
```

And that's the rendering code:

```
void OpenGLWindow::render()
{
    if(!isExposed())
        return;

    _context->makeCurrent(this);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(_shaderProgram);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _positionBufferObject);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0);

    _context->swapBuffers(this);
}
```

I am trying to draw a simple triangle using a vertex and fragment shader. The problem is that the triangle is not showing up when the core profile is set. Only when I set the OpenGL version to 2.0 or when I use the compatibility profile, it shows up. From my point of view that doesn't make any sense because I am not using fixed functionality at all. What am I missing?

Comment: What are the results when you do the same using PaintEvent or PaintGL in a QGLWidget?

Comment: QGLWidget is not related to the new Qt API for openGL if I remember correctly. It uses QSurface and QWindow. Could you check after `_context->makeCurrent(this);` that the format of the surface and the one of the context are 3.3 Core ? I had the same issue. I don't have my home computer at hand so I can't browse back my history to give you the link to a solution right now. Also take a look at this : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html#versionFunctions. Could you check if the functions pointer you get is not null ?

Comment: Both the context and the surface are 3.3 Core, the functions pointer is not null.

Comment: You need to create and bind a vertex array object (VAO). Using vertex buffers without a VAO is deprecated in the core profile. This has come up a few times, I'll try and find a duplicate later.

Comment: You mean removed. There are only a few things that are deprecated in core profiles, like wide lines.

Comment: Right, yes, I meant "deprecated" in the sense of not available anymore, not just marked deprecated for possible future removal. Sorry about using the wrong terminology.

Comment: Thanks, I'd mark this as the answer if it was possible!